# google places api accessibility

Tags: python, google-places-api

I'm having trouble finding the documentation to call the accessiblity attributes Google recently added using python. I intend to populate a map of my city with the accessiblity attributes for all restaurants. Please help

Comment: Questions asking members of the site to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not available yet in the Google places API but you can file a request for it using the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309%22issue%20tracker%22).

Comment: thank you, thats not the answer i necessarily wanted but thanks nonetheless.